# IEFE (immediately executed function expression) in Google Spreadsheet Script Editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I tried to define some IEFE style Javascript functions in [Google Spreadsheet](https://sheets.google.com)'s Script Editor (Tools > Script Editor):

```
function sayHello() {
  return "HELLO";
}

var World = (function () {
  return {
    'say': function() {
      return "WORLD";
    }
  };
}();
```

So in a cell, `=sayHello()` will work, but not `=World.say()`. I want to use IEFE style because I would like to namespace my various JS functions for better management and maintainability.

Is this possible? I tried other IEFE ways to define functions but still failed.

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#naming)

> The name of a custom function must be declared with the syntax `function myFunction()`, not `var myFunction = new Function()`.

So, IIFE/anonymous functions and functions inside objects cannot be used as custom functions.